# how does $I = Prn$ become $P=\frac{I}{rn}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does this simple interest formula become from $I=Prn$ to $P=\frac{I}{rn}$ ? I can't understand them. Though this formula is correct but I want to know how it works. Can anybody please explain this transformation process step by step? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added MathJax. If the formatting is incorrect, please say it.

Comment: There is only one step: divide both sides by $r_n$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I have reformatted accurately now. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: To isolate $P$, you have to "remove" $r$ and $n$ on the right side. Since there is an invisible multiply-sign between the letters, you must simply apply the opposite operation, in this case dividing, first by $r$ , then by $n$ (or just by $rn$).

Comment: rn /= r$_n$ @mvpq!

Comment: @WilliamElliot the question was edited after I commented

Comment: Multiple both sides by 1/rn .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in $I = Prn$ the $P$ and the $r$ and the $n$ are multiplied together.  The opposite of multiplication is division.   Since $I$ and $Prn$ are equal, when you divide them by the same number, you get equal quantities.  So divide them both by $r$ and you get

$$\frac{I}{r} = \frac{Prn}{r}.$$

If you divide both of these quantities by $n$, you get

$$\frac{I}{rn} = \frac{Prn}{rn}.$$

Then this last guy can be written

$$\frac{Prn}{rn} = P\frac{rn}{rn} = P\cdot 1 = P.$$

So you have

$$\frac{I}{rn} = \frac{Prn}{rn} = P.$$